Express is sending empty response body with sub routes, but works fine with root route
in routes.ts file:
const router:Router = express.Router()

// Route to get all blogs

router.get('/',async (req:Request,res:Response)=>{
   
    res.status(200).send("message sent")   

})

router.get('/admin',async (req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    console.log("here")

    res.status(200).send('new token sent!')

})


and so in frontend (which I used Next):

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/').then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data)
    })

  },[])


in another useEffect call, where i am trying to send request to /admin:

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/admin/').then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)

        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(`error ${err}`)
        })
    },[])


in first useEffect() , i am getting the response as expected ("message sent")
but when trying to make request to /admin i get empty response data
Please NOTE THAT i was trying to log that route in express side, `console.log("here"), but it was NOT BEING logged at all.

note that i tried making other sub routes in express like /example, and it same issue.
here is my app.ts:

const app: Express = express();

const corsOptions:CorsOptions ={
  origin:['http://127.0.0.1:3000','http://localhost:3000'],
  methods:"*",
  allowedHeaders:'*'
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.json())




app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use('/',router)


Please execute the command http://localhost:8000/admin DIRECTLY from your browser and check the response at client and the server. Alternatively please execute the following command from command line,  curl http://localhost:8000/admin

@WeDoTheBest4You in both cases, response body is empty.

Did you get this  console.log("here") at the server console?

no i did not get it.

What is the latest output of this  console.log([server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port});

pretty much that it. nothing else is shown.

Is the issue still persisting ?

i created a new project in which express is set with js (default) rather than ts, which means there was probably some ts issue? shrug

The below code works here. Request please use it to check with yours.
server.js
const router = require('./router');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: '*',
  allowedHeaders: '*',
};
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening @3000'));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use('/', router);

router.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Route to get all blogs
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('message sent');
});

router.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('here');
  res.status(200).send('new token sent!');
});

module.exports = router;

Running the server
nodemon server.js

Output:
   Server console: 
     Listening @3000

Testing from client
$ curl http://localhost:3000/admin/

Output:
   Server console
      here
   Response at client 
      new token sent!   

